# Альтернатива NotePad++ для Mac или как быстро просеивать текст?

Tags: sublime-text, notepad++, текстовый-редактор

По работе приходится построчно доставать информацию из текста. Например, есть несколько тысяч строк. Их нужно профильтровать, оставив только те, которые содержат определённую подстроку. В нотпаде это делается элементарно: поиск с закладкой; вырезать строки без закладки. Причём, можно искать в том числе и регуляркой. Способную удобно делать то же самое альтернативу для мака пока не нашел. Куча приложений, но нужный функционал в них либо отсутствует либо находится где-то очень глубоко. Мне бы что-то простое. Пока поставил sublime text, но пока так в нём и не разобрался. Не ясно есть ли там вообще то что мне нужно. Может тут кто подскажет? Мне бы прям инструкцию)